# Сервер выдает неправельные MIME типы css файлов

Tags: apache, openserver, mime

Решил использовать OWL Carousel 2, скачал файлы.
Сервер выдает неправельные MIME типы css файлов только от OWL Carousel 2,

> Таблица стилей
>   http://trash.ru:81/Scin/plagins/OwlCarousel2/owl.carousel.css не была
>   загружена, потому что её MIME-тип («text/html») не
>   «text/css».WebRequest.jsm:217:17 Таблица стилей
>   http://trash.ru:81/Scin/plagins/OwlCarousel2/owl.theme.default.css не
>   была загружена, потому что её MIME-тип («text/html») не
>   «text/css».WebRequest.jsm:217:17

Пробовал в конфиге сервера добавить  AddType text/css .css и AddType text/css .min.css, не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил копипастом в вручную созданные файлы

Answer (score 0):

Имел похожую проблему. Подозреваю - из-за наличия русскоязычных коментов. Их там много и вручную лень выстригать. Но зато когда подставил сжатый CSS (сжимал через closure-stylesheets.jar) то ругаться перестало.